# Formula for speed of rigidly connected objects with one "turning off" of the line?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics, distance

In the diagram below I have two objects traveling up the diagram on the black track at some speed *s*, separated by distance *D* connected by a breakable rigid rod. Further along the straight-line track, there is a turnout consisting of an arc of the circle with radius *R*. The top object will take the turnout, the follower will continue straight, eventually breaking the connection when the distance between the two objects exceeds *D*.

While the two objects *are* connected, how can I calculate the speed over time of the follower as the leader enters and continues through the turnout?

I've used the equation for the circle and numerically calculated the required position of the follower at various times, but it's messy, surely there's a more direct way to do this given speed *s*, radius *R* and distance *D*?

Edit: After further machinations, I took the tack of starting at the instant the leader gets to the turnout and with the formula for the position of the follower, I took the derivative to get the speed of the follower on the straight line, where $\theta$ is the angle of the leader in the arc, getting

> $\frac{\pi  \mathcal{R} \sin (\pi  \theta ) (\mathcal{R}-\mathcal{R}
>  \cos (\pi  \theta ))}{\sqrt{\mathcal{D}^2-(\mathcal{R}-\mathcal{R}
>  \cos (\pi  \theta ))^2}}+\pi  \mathcal{R} \cos (\pi  \theta )$

Minimizing that for $\mathcal{R}=30$ and $\mathcal{D}=10$ I got ~0.992, i.e., while connected the follower's speed is at minimum .992 of the leader's speed along the arc.

This seems too high intuitively (that is, imagining it, it seems one would need to slow down much more to keep the distance constant as the leader started the turn).

Cheers.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should trust my mathematics and give myself the benefit of the doubt in my physics recollection - indeed, after graphing it, intuition failed me, and the slow-down required is very minor:

[image]